# Find and cache elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am looking for all `<a>` tags under an element. 
I then find the `href` of each `<a>` tag and get the elements which has those ID's:

```
var links = element.find("a");
var panes = links.map(function () { 
    return $("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]); 
});
```

I will use one or more of the links and panes in my code.

1. What is the best way to cache these elements?
   I am not sure that I am doing it right.
2. I added a class to the first link and first pane:

   ```
   $(links[0]).addClass("active");  
   panes[0].addClass("active");
   ```

   Why do I needed to use `$(links[0])` instead of `links[0]` to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The array dereferencing operator (`[]`) in jQuery mimics the behavior of [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), which returns an HTML element, not the jQuery object.

Quote:

> The .get() method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object.
>
> Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so we can use the array dereferencing operator to get at the list item instead:
>
> `console.log( $( "li" )[ 0 ] );`

Instead you can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) which will return the jQuery object. For example:

```
links.eq(0).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of your confusion is that you handle two different kinds of objects:

- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) objects, which are specific to the jQuery library.
- Arrays of [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) objects, which are part of good old DOM API.

I'll quote the docs:

> A jQuery object **contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM)
>   elements** that have been created from an HTML string or selected from a
>   document. [...]
>
> The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array; it has a length
>   property and **the elements in the object can be accessed by their
>   numeric indices [0] to [length-1]**.

So `links` is an instance of `jQuery` but `links[0]` is an instance of `Node`. The brackets are a convenience wrapper provided by the library.

*(No idea about what you want to know about caching.)*